# When running dask on a local computer, should I create a `client` object?

Tags: python, dask

I run `dask` distributed jobs on a local computer, I want to utilize all the available cpus's and don't care about the diagnostic dashboard. Are there any advantages of creating a `Client` object in this scenario?

I'm asking because creating such an object takes some time during the startup of a script, and I would like to cut this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly covered in the documentation: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html

In short: maybe, depending on the type of workload you are running. Threads have lowest latency and memory sharing, but will not parallelise code that needs the GIL. The distributed scheduler allows you more configuration, e.g., thread/process mix, memory limits and such.